# how to save user input in another page without overwritting the previous user input in PHP

Tags: php, variables, session, user-input

i want to save multiple user information in another page in PHP. i have a form where user input some information,like name, city...so on & i want to save those information in a table.

I have used session but it overwrite the previous record.

```
    h3>Contact Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form  method="post" >
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

other page.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
?>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $name ?> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is used to store the value for temporary period of time. Here is how to save form data in session. Later you can fetch it where you want.

HTML

```
<form action="other_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="mobile">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP (other_page.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['mobile'] = $_POST['mobile'];
}

?>
```

How to fetch data stored in session in HTML (other_page.php or another)

```
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['mobile'];?></h1>
```

"*I have used session but it overwrite the previous record*".

Exact. $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'] set a new value to $_SESSION['name'] **eachtime you submit the form**.

If you want persistence in your data, you have to store it in the database.

NEXT STEP (other_page.php)

Suppose you have configured a connection to a bdd mysql server for example.

```
<?php 
    //Initializing the session 
    session_start(); 
      
    //writing MySQL Query to insert the details 
    $insert_query = 'insert into yourtable( 
                    name, 
                    email, 
                    mobile
                    ) values ( 
                    ' . $_POST['name'] . ", 
                    " . $_POST['email'] . ", 
                    " . $_POST['mobile'] . ", 

                    );" 
  
    //let's run the query 
    mysql_query($insert_query); 
    ?>
```

Comment: appreciate your assist. i have solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome @FSO. If my answer is useful and if it answers your question do not hesitate to indicate it on this post. Up arrow "The answer is helpful". Check "Accept as the answer". Good continuation.